# How to record a live rtsp played bt VideoView (Vitamio)

Tags: android, android-videoview, vitamio

I'm trying to record live stream video played by vitamio videoView.
right now i'm using MediaRecorded but it's just not working.

how should i do that? i have those 3 main recording methods.

is there another method to record live stream?

```
holder = mVideoView.getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            initRecorder();
        }

    });

 private void initRecorder() {
    if (recorder == null) recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
    //recorder.setCamera(mCamera);

    recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
    //       mrecorder.setOutputFormat(8);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    recorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(512 * 1000);
    recorder.setVideoFrameRate(25);
    recorder.setVideoSize(352, 288);
    recorder.setOutputFile(Utils.getTuracoFolder() + "/video.mp4");

    try {
        recorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // This is thrown if the previous calls are not called with the
        // proper order
        e.printStackTrace();
        TLog.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        TLog.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}

private void toggleRecording() {
    if (recorder == null) return;
    if (recording) {
        try {
            recorder.stop();
            recorder.reset();
            initRecorder();
            recording = false;
            TLog.d(TAG, "Stopped Recording");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            TLog.d(TAG, "Error  - " + ex.getMessage());
        }

    } else {
        try {
            recorder.start();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            TLog.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        Log.v(TAG, "Recording Started");
        recording = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i have done it but with ffmpeg. so do this to download m3u8 streaming using ffmpeg.

update you gradle.built

```
dependencies {

compile 'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2'
```

}

now in you activity class write this

```
 FFmpeg ffmpeg;
```

//command that will create new file mani.mp4 file in root

```
String  cmdd="-i http://rt-a.akamaihd.net/ch_04@325608/720p.m3u8 -c:a copy -c:v copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc "+ new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/mani.mp4").getAbsolutePath();
String[] cmd = cmdd.split(" ");


 ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

    try {
        ffmpeg.loadBinary(new LoadBinaryResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onStart() {}

            @Override
            public void onFailure() {}

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {}

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {}
        });

    } catch (FFmpegNotSupportedException e) {
        // Handle if FFmpeg is not supported by device

        Log.e("com",e.toString());
    }
 try {
        // to execute "ffmpeg -version" command you just need to pass "-version"
        ffmpeg.execute(cmd, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onStart() {}


            @Override
            public void onProgress(String message) {
               // will print information about every new frame it find on given link
               Log.e("com",message);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(String message) {
                }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String message) {
                }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {}
        });
    } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
        // Handle if FFmpeg is already running

    }
```

to stop downloading run this on button click

```
ffmpeg.killRunningProcesses();
```

Remember to add internet and read/ write permission

Comment: I declare permission in manifest, and change compileSdk to 15, It show:Permission denied.